# Generate a type from another type and change fields to optional

Tags: python, type-hinting

I have this type:

```py
class SomeResource:
    id: int
    name: str
```

And I need this type:

```py
class SomeResourceQuery:
    id: Optional[int]
    name: Optional[str]
```

But I'd like to avoid having to write it by hand. Is it possible to generate this `SomeResourceQuery` type from the `SomeResource` type? Just convert all the types of the fields to optional. (Update: Already optional fields can stay optional - no nested optionals.)

I plan to use this `SomeResourceQuery` in a repository, like this:

```py
class SomeResourceRepository:
    def get_one_or_none(self, query: SomeResourceQuery) -> Optional[SomeResource]:
        ...
```

---

Update: Just to show what I'm thinking currently:

```py
class SomeResource:
    id: int
    name: str


# I don't want to write this by hand:
# class SomeResourceQuery:
#     id: Optional[int]
#     name: Optional[str]

# So what can I do here to make all fields that are not already optional, optional?
SomeResourceQuery = type("SomeResourceQuery", SomeResource) # What to do here?
```

Comment: How would you like an already-optional field to be treated?

Comment: Good question! For my purposes it's enough to just have that stay optional (no nested optionals).

Comment: Can `SomeResource` have any methods or just type annotations?

Comment: In my case there are just fields in these classes. No methods. They just hold data.

Comment: How about using dataclasses? You could make a function that calls [make_dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.make_dataclass) with the parent class and map the fields to be optional from [fields](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.fields)?

Comment: I could use dataclasses if that's easier, if type hints are preserved in the generated/created type in the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `type` constructor to construct the new type with the appropriate annotations.

```py
def construct_query_class(cls: type) -> type:
    annotations = {key: typing.Optional[value]
                    for key, value in cls.__annotations__.items()}

    return dataclasses.dataclass(type(cls.__name__ + 'Query', (),
                                      {'__annotations__': annotations}))

class SomeResource:
    id: int
    name: str

SomeResourceQuery = construct_query_class(SomeResource) # type: typing.Any
```

Comment: If you need to support resource classes that inherit from other dataclasses, you should use [`dataclasses.fields`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.fields) to make sure you get all the fields.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering! I have some issues with this that I'm not sure how to solve. My editor is not giving me tab-completion on the fields of `SomeResourceQuery`, and mypy complains that the fields to not exist. I've pasted my program and the mypy error here: https://pastebin.com/ckHmWBBZ

Comment: To squash the mypy error, you can add the comment `# type: typing.Any` to the last line of my answer.  This is a [known issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2477) with mypy.  As for PyCharm, someone who knows more about that program could perhaps correct me but I suspect that you're plain out of luck.  Dynamic type construction makes semantic analysis tricky.